# Displaying entity form on node page

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

I'm a bit new to Drupal, but I'm on a project, where the most handy stuff is drupal. I only used it for 6 months, then I used mvc-s and stuff. Now I'm back to it.

The project is kinda simple. There is a site admin, who creates events and a registration form for that event (almost every registration form is different).

I want to display that entity form on the event page. I downloaded entityform blocks and it works, but I was just wondering if there is a module out there that creates a field type with the entityform types and the user can easily chose the entityform to display on the event page, when creating a new event.

If there is no such a module, then can it be solved by writing a custom field type? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) lets you do this.

1. Add an entity reference field.
2. Target Type: Entityform Type.
3. If you want to limit the options for a user, you can create an entity reference view for entityform types and select it in the options.
4. Go to your content type's "Manage Display" and select "Rendered Entity" for the field.
5. Or for Panels, add a Context>Relationship>Entityform Type from Node.
6. Add it to the page under Page Content>Rendered Entityform Type.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! If I could upvote it 1000 times, I would :D